# How to work with images manually in python

Tags: python, image-processing

I wanted to know how I could work with images manually in python i.e. without Pillow or openCV e.t.c.

beginning code:

```
image_file = open("myFile.jpg", 'rb')
file_data = image_file.read()

integer_values_for_pixels = []
for pixel_value in file_data:
    integer_values_for_pixels.append(pixel_value)
```

From this code, I noticed integer values get stored in the list 'integer_values_for_pixels'. Note: I'm assuming those integer values are for the pixels. If its not, I want to know what those integer values represent...thus far I know its the binary data, where each of the integers is represented by a byte in binary (I think).

I kind of want to know when opening the file in binary mode, how do I obtain the pixel matrix which I can the perform operations on.

By the way, the image I used was 735 * 500, 24 Bit depth and size was 78442 bytes. How is 78442 bytes calculated from those preceding numbers?

Comment: Most image formats do not store their pixels in convenient matrix form. For example, [one of the more popular jpeg codecs requires a discrete cosine transform to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_codec_example). If you're not afraid of college-level mathematics, you can usually discover how to decipher an image file by googling "<image file extension> file format".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image in encoded with some encoding based on what file extension is used to save the image. For a simple example, see [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). The pixel value are never saved as it is and hence it is useless to access the bytes directly.

#### An extreme example

A single most frequent byte(s) can be represent by a single bit in huffman coding (lossless) and hence a single byte can even therotically represent 8 consecutive numbers. If the numbers are say `float 64`, with same number repeating 8 times, `8 x 64/8 = 64` bytes can be represented by a single byte.